# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException (I'm really new to this)

Tags: java

I'm having problems with a simple code, I've seen this problem everywhere but I can't seem to find a fix to work with me, then again I started learning java only 3 weeks ago.

This is my error after compiling and running

```
$java -Xmx512M -Xms64M RolePlayingGame
Name your adventurer.
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
    at RolePlayingGame.main(RolePlayingGame.java:11)
```

And this is my code. This isn't urgent, I'll probably learn it in class sometime soon but I'd still like to know, it's not for a class or anything, it's only a pet project of mine. Here's my small amount of code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RolePlayingGame
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    int EnemyHack, EnemySlash, EnemyStab, EnemyBlock, Hack, Slash, Stab, Block, Potion, Health, EnemyHealth, EnemyHealth2, EnemyHealth3, EnemyHealth4, EnemyHealth5, Level;
    String Hack2, Slash2, Stab2, Block2, Potion2, Name;

    Level = 1;
    Health = 20+(Level*5);

    System.out.println("Name your adventurer.");
    Name = keyboard.next();
    System.out.println("Your name is " + Name + " .");


    System.out.println("You're passing through a murky forest.");
    System.out.println("You've been travelling many days. And you are tired.");
    System.out.println("There has been a heavy fog for the past week and it");
    System.out.println("has begun to grate on your nerves. Recently however,");
    System.out.println("you've noticed the fog lessening. As the fog lessens");
    System.out.println("you begin to notice shapes, you slowly draw your sword.");
    System.out.println("As you pass through the fog a demon lunges at you.");
    System.out.println("You let forth a battlecry and begin to fight.");
    System.out.println("The enemies health is " + EnemyHealth + " whereas yours is " + Health + " . Do you want to flee?");




    }
}
```

After I added the Level and Health I also started getting a new error while compiling. Might've been the site I was using (I was using an online compiler, site went down about a minute after I started getting the error).

Comment: Please follow Java naming conventions. Non-final variables should start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: "I was using an online compiler" While online compilers may work, their quality, performance, and features differ between compilers. I would advise you to, with permission, install Eclipse and the JDK on a computer you have access to, and use that instead of the online compiler. Eclipse offers features such as errorchecking, auto-completion with libraries, and better management of projects.

Comment: Unfamiliar with the non-final variables naming convention, started REALLY recently, and have only a few hours practice. Earlier today I was stoked to get a dice rolling code working by myself. 
I installed JDK and was having troubles with it. Personally I like a compiler that will compile it and then try to run it, and I don't know if Eclipse is like that. I'll check it out though thank you.

Comment: There are plenty of starter's tutorials on the internet. I would suggest starting with something easy, not a game, or perhaps something like hangman. But better is something like calculating the consumption of a car for 100 miles given a distance and the total consumption. Get familiar with the tools decently before going ahead.

Comment: I just feel like I'll be able to practice more varied things here. And in greater amounts.

Answer (score 3):

The error lies here:
`Name = keyboard.next();`

You should use
`Name = keyboard.nextLine();`

The java.util.Scanner.next() method finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. 
A complete token is preceded and followed by an input that matches the delimiter pattern, which is a blank space by default.

You may want to take a look at the documentation of the [Scanner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

You should also take a look at the [Java naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html)